# How powerful are Moranth Cussers?

Tags: malazan, steven-erikson

In The Malazan Book of the Fallen, we see the Malazan Army using Moranth munitions at many points throughout the story.  I can get a sense of how destructive most of these are (sharpers, crackers, flamers, etc..), but while reading *The Bonehunters* (specifically the siege of Y'Ghatan) I realize I don't have a good sense of the destructive power of cussers.  I initially thought they were similar in power to a stick of dynamite, but looking at videos of sticks of dynamite exploding doesn't get near the destruction I envision a cusser causing.

**Are there any insights into how powerful a cusser would be in terms of explosives we have in reality?  Are there even explosives in reality to compare cussers to in order to get a sense of their destructive scale?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Malazan Wiki](http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Moranth_munitions) has a section on cussers. It describes them as being similar to a [satchel charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satchel_charge).

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  The destruction of a satchel charge from the few videos I found agrees with the expectation I had in my head.  Thanks!